# snowflake - Is there a way to URI decode external tables file name?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an external table which reads files from S3 and partitioned by date and application name.
I'm trying to parse the application name into a column however i need the value to be decoded.

**example** I have a file name which is `/dwh/some_table/2021-06-01/new%2Fapplicatio%nFname/file.csv.gz`

I want to be able to query the table with
`select * from some_table where app_name = 'new application name'`.
instead of `where app_name = 'new%2Fapplicatio%nFname'`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE some_table(
    date timestamp AS TO_TIMESTAMP split_part(metadata$filename, '/',  4)),    
    app_name varchar(64) as split_part(metadata$filename, '/',  5)
    .....
  PARTITION BY (date, app_name)
  LOCATION=@SOME_LOCATION
  AUTO_REFRESH = true
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV, SKIP_HEADER = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very straight forward to replace with a regex, but here it is:

```
SET MYREGEX = 'new%2Fapplicatio%nFname';
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE($MYREGEX, '(F){1,}',' '), '(%|[2]){0,}', '');
```

I get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's not very useful if i want it to decode all encoded characters and not only `%2F`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but decoding all characters is not an easy process, especially if you don't know them in advance.